# Clopen Set $Z(e)$ in the ring $C(X)$, where $e$ is an idempotent function

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

Let $C(X)$ denote the ring of all continuous real-valued functions on a completely regular Hausdorff space $X$.

Let $e:X\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be an idempotent function in $C(X)$ (i.e $e^2=e$)

Suppose that $Z(e)=\{x\in X| e(x)=0\}$. I need to to show $Z(e)$ is clopen.

Clear it is a closed set. But why is it open?

Comment: $Z(e) = \{x\in X \mid e(x)\neq 1 \}$.

Comment: @Slade I don't get . Sorry

Comment: @J.Doe X can be any space.

Comment: $Z$ is the preimage of an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x\in X$, $e(x)^2 = e(x)\rightarrow e(x)(e(x) -1) = 0$, so $e(x) = 0$ or $e(x) = 1$.

So $X = \{x: e(x) = 0\} \cup \{x: e(x) =1\} = e^{-1}[\{0\}] \cup e^{-1}[\{1\}]$.

Both these sets are closed (as inverse images of closed sets under a continuous $e$) and disjoint, so each other's complement. So both are open as well. The first set is just $Z(e)$.